# Weird . notation in C? What is this called and can someone explain?

Tags: c, pointers

I don't know how to title this because I'm stumped. 
I am looking at some C code that looks like this:

```
struct my_struct const mystruct = {
.data = &my_data;
}
```

What is this . notation? Can someone explain to me? Give some better examples? I searched up and down my C notes and books, I see no reference to this. Is this some throwback from Assembly language mixed into C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Designated Initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). It added to C in C99 standard. You can learn more about it at the link.